# Representing a Stencil of a Finite Difference Operator with Mathematica's Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d, visualization, finite-difference-method

I have the following finite difference operator:
$$
Lu_{ijk}:=
du_{ijk} +c(u_{i-1,j,k} + u_{i+1,j,k} + u_{i,j-1,k} + u_{i,j+1,k}  + u_{i,j,k-1} + u_{i,j,k+1})\\
-u_{i-1,j+1,k}-u_{i-1,j-1,k} - u_{i-1,j,k-1} - u_{i-1,j,k+1}  \\
 -u_{i+1,j+1,k}-u_{i+1,j-1,k}  - u_{i+1,j,k-1} - u_{i+1,j,k+1}  \\
- u_{i,j+1,k-1} - u_{i,j-1,k-1} - u_{i, j+1,k+1} - u_{i,j-1,k+1},
$$
where $d$ and $c$ are known constants.
This is way too complex of an expression to expect people to understand, so I want to represent it by a [stencil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-point_stencil):

[image: 5-point stencil]

For example, I'd put a sphere of one color (representing $du_{ijk}$) at the origin, a sphere of another color at $(-1,0,0)$, (representing $cu_{i-1,j,k}$), and so on, and finally spheres of a final color at $(-1,1,0)$ (representing $-u_{i-1,j+1,k}$). My preliminary *Mathematica* commands are:

```
Graphics3D[{Specularity[White, 10], Red, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}],
            Blue, Sphere[{0, 0, 1}], Sphere[{1, 0, 0}], Sphere[{-1, 0, 0}],
            Sphere[{0, -1, 0}], Sphere[{0, 0, -1}],
            Green, Sphere[{1, 1, 0}], Sphere[{1, 0, 1}]}, Boxed -> False]
```

but these spheres are way too big and cover each other up. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take it in steps:

1. Extract the coefficients and locations into an appropriate data structure.
2. Use that data structure to create the graphics.

By examining the `FullForm` of the original expression, we can cobble a rule to find the key data: the coefficients $c$, $d$, and $-1$ and the offsets to the indexes.  First, the expression itself:

```
s = Subscript;
exp = d s[u, i, j, k] + 
  c (s[u, i - 1, j, k] + s[u, i + 1, j, k] + s[u, i, j - 1, k] + 
     s[u, i, j + 1, k] + s[u, i, j, k - 1] + s[u, i, j, k + 1]) - 
  s[u, i - 1, j + 1, k] - s[u, i - 1, j - 1, k] - s[u, i - 1, j, k - 1] - s[u, i - 1, j, k + 1] - 
  s[u, i + 1, j + 1, k] - s[u, i + 1, j - 1, k] - s[u, i + 1, j, k - 1] - s[u, i + 1, j, k + 1] - 
  s[u, i, j + 1, k - 1] - s[u, i, j - 1, k - 1] - 
  s[u, i, j + 1, k + 1] - s[u, i, j - 1, k + 1]
```

`Expand` pairs the coefficients with the subscripts and `Cases` extracts the essential information:

```
data = Cases[Expand@exp, Times[c_, s[u, i_, j_, k_]] :> {c, i, j, k}];
data // MatrixForm
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  -1 & -1+i & -1+j & k \\
>  -1 & -1+i & j & -1+k \\
>  c & -1+i & j & k \\
>  \cdots \\
>  -1 & 1+i & 1+j & k
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

We are really interested in the *offsets* to the central index $(i,j,k)$, so one more step to extract them (via `Replace` this time) will be helpful.  After doing it, let's group the offsets by common coefficient using `GatherBy`:

```
spec = GatherBy[{First@#, 
         Replace[Rest@#,  {Plus[x_?NumberQ, i_] ->  x, x_Symbol -> 0}, 1]} & /@ data, First]
```

To illustrate, here is what the first few elements of the first entry in `spec` look like:

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  -1 & \{-1,-1,0\} \\
>  -1 & \{-1,0,-1\} \\
>  -1 & \{-1,0,1\} \\
>   \cdots \\
>  -1 & \{1,1,0\}
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

(You might be happier just entering the data in this format, or something close to it, at the outset: it's easier than entering all those subscripts.)

Choose some colors:

```
colors = Array[Hue[# / Length@spec, .8, .8] &, Length@spec];
```

The rest is easy.  Let's make sure to include some visual cues such as thin lines connecting the base point to its neighbors, for otherwise this will look only like a random jumble of balls.

```
Graphics3D[ { 
  Table[{Specularity[White, 10], 
    GrayLevel[0.7], Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, Last@#}, 0.025] & /@ spec[[i]],
    colors[[i]], Sphere[Last@#, .2] & /@ spec[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length@spec}]}, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"i", "j", "k"} ]
```

(I leave the creation of a color key as an exercise :-).)

[image: Figure]

Comment: If I can nitpick... I prefer horizontal and vertical connections so that it is clearer which point is located where w.r.t. the center.

Comment: @rubenvb That's a great idea.  How would you implement it?  In this diagram, renderings of such connections would all run into one another. I can think of some possibilities, such as introducing a light 3D grid, or a set of nested transparent cubes, or other such visual references, but perhaps you have a specific form of visualization in mind?

Comment: no idea really, I am terrible at drawing with Mathematica. I don't see how they would run into each other though. Something like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_direction_implicit_method) comes to mind though.

Comment: @rubenvb Thank you: I see what you mean. There are arbitrary elements to that diagram--it could be drawn in many equivalent ways.  However, something like it could be implemented in *Mathematica*, provided we settle on rules to determine which sets of line segments to draw.

Answer (score 6):

Although you haven't exactly asked this, you might like to generate your graphic automatically by applying pattern matching on your difference operator. The basic idea is as below:

```
Clear[i, j, k];

op = Plus @@ 
  MapThread[Subscript[u, i - #1, j - #2, k - #3] &, 
   RotateRight[{0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, #] & /@ {0, 2, 4}]
```

Giving $op = u_{i-1,j,k}+u_{i,j-1,k}+u_{i,j,k-1}+u_{i,j,k}+u_{i,j,k+1}+u_{i,j+1,k}+u_{i+1,j,k}$

```
Graphics3D[
 Level[op /. 
     Subscript[_, i_, j_, k_] :> Sphere[{i, j, k}, .1] /. {i -> 0, 
     j -> 0, k -> 0}, {-3}] /. {s : Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, _] :> 
    Sequence[Red, s], s_Sphere :> Sequence[Blue, s]}, Axes -> True]
```

[image: 3D Stencil?]

*Disclaimer: I'm a fairly new and rather unsophisticated Mathematica user, so my code is probably crap and likely to break if you breathe on it too hard, but anyway, there you have it.*

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is what you're after. Anyway:

```
r = .1; 
Graphics3D[{Specularity[White, 10], 
            Red, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r], 
            Blue, Sphere[{0, 0, 1}, r], Sphere[{1, 0, 0}, r], Sphere[{-1, 0, 0}, r],  
                                        Sphere[{0, -1, 0}, r], Sphere[{0, 0, -1}, r],
            Green, Sphere[{1, 1, 0}, r], Sphere[{1, 0, 1}, r]}, Boxed -> False, 
            Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, that was really easy! Thanks!